# Deleting 3d dynamic array C++

Tags: c++

I make a 3d dynamic array by this using this code

```
//layer = 2

//levelSize.x = 100

//levelSize.y = 100

level_array = new int**[layer];

    for(int i = 0; i < layer; ++i)
    {
        level_array[i] = new int*[(int)levelSize.x];
        for(int j = 0; j < levelSize.x; ++j)
            level_array[i][j] = new int[(int)levelSize.y];
    }
```

but when I want to delete it, the program crashes

```
for(int i = 0; i != levelSize.x; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j != levelSize.y; ++j)
        {
            delete[] level_array[i][j];
        }
        delete[] level_array[i];

    }
    delete[] level_array;
```

I don't know where is wrong in the code of deleting an array.

Please help me check the code, Thanks

Comment: I haven't done C++ in a while, but shouldn't `delete[] level_array` delete the array?

Comment: @zachlatta, Not recursively.

Comment: I question having a 3D array in the first place, but use `std::vector` or likewise (preferably wrapping it in a `Matrix3D` class with a 1D array) and you won't have to delete anything.

Comment: Most likely, the program crashes because you are writing beyond array boundaries somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You allocate memory for array with dimensions `[layer][levelSize.x][levelSize.y]`, but while deleting you operate with it like with array with dimensions `[levelSize.x][levelSize.y][somenting]`.

```
for(int i = 0; i != layer; ++i)
//                  ^^^^^ not levelSize.x
{
    for(int j = 0; j != levelSize.x; ++j)
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ not levelSize.y
    {
        delete[] level_array[i][j];
    }
    delete[] level_array[i];

}
delete[] level_array;
```

Comment: why you do not need to do : delete level_array[i][j][k] where k iterate from 0 to levelSize.y ?

Comment: Because `level_array[i][j][k]` is a value, not an allocated array

Answer (score 1):

Add this command to the end, otherwise the pointer will be at the top of the stack.

`level_array = nullptr;`

Comment: @ T Nguyen : yes assigning a pointer to null is too efficient which means it points to NULL address not the previous address because delete only frees memory. this helps when trying to dereference  NULL pointer which issues in segfault which make us aware. if we dereference a deleted pointer without assigning  NULL to it, it may gives us a garbage value without complaining and that's the disaster

Comment: In that case the best choice is to just use `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

it's so important to make difference between deleting a single dim array and multi-dim allocated on the heap:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

    int*** ptrInt = new int**[3];

    for(int i(0); i < 3; i++)
        ptrInt[i] = new int*[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            ptrInt[i][j] = new int[3];
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            for(int k(0); k < 3; k++)
                ptrInt[i][j][k] = k;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            for(int k(0); k < 3; k++)
                cout << "ptrInt[" << i << "][" << j << "][" << k << "]: " << ptrInt[i][j][k] << endl;
    }

    // now freeing memory:

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            delete[] ptrInt[i][j];
        delete[] ptrInt[i];
    }
    delete[] ptrInt;


    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```