# Error while deleting 3D dynamic array in Pascal

Tags: arrays, pointers, memory-management, multidimensional-array, pascal

The point is to make it work with pointers. Also, I found [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381025/deleting-3d-dynamic-array-c) with C++. Its not working with Pascal, well, I prob. missed something.

1) I make types and variable for my pointers:

```
type
  PReal = ^double;
  PPReal = ^PReal;
var
  data : ^PPReal;
```

2) This is how I allocate memory (x,y,z are dimensions):

```
GetMem( data, sizeof(PPReal)*x );
for i:=0 to x-1 do begin
  GetMem( (data+i)^, sizeof(PReal)*y );
  for j:=0 to y-1 do begin
    GetMem( ((data+i)^+j)^, sizeof(real)*z );
  end;
end;
```

3) And this is how I try to Dispose() it:

```
for i:=0 to x-1 do begin
  for j:=0 to y-1 do begin
    Dispose( ((data+i)^+j) );
  end;
  Dispose( (data+i) );
end;
Dispose( data );
```

However, I'm getting 216(memory access) or 204(invalid pointer operation) runtime errors. Like [this](http://pastebin.com/q1JKYyTu). Full [code](http://pastebin.com/CZgmb7rT) (FreePascal IDE)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not use pascal for what it is known for, type safety. See [Multidimensional dynamic array](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Example:_Multidimensional_dynamic_array) for examples how to work with dynamic arrays in pascal.

Comment: Does pascal do C-style pointer+integer addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last dispose is mirrored to its getmem, but the other two not. Fix that and it works:

```
  for i:=0 to x-1 do begin
    for j:=0 to y-1 do begin
    writeln(i,' ',j,' *');
    Dispose( ((data+i)^+j)^ );
  end;
  writeln(i,' ',j);
  Dispose( (data+i)^ );
end;
Dispose( data );
```

p.s. freemem is the logical companion to getmem, as dispose is to new.